# Why does the compiler allow a function to return a value that is stored as a reference

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors

Can anybody explain why this code does not generate a compiler error?

```
class Foo
{
   public:
      int _x;
};

Foo getFoo()
{
   Foo myfoo;
   myfoo._x = 10;
   return myfoo;
}


int _tmain()
{
   // shouldn't this line of code be a compiler error?
   Foo& badfoo = getFoo();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your text is contradictory. Your former text says "it compiles without error, why?" and the latter says "this does not compile because of an error, why?". This code should *not* work, you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: Also, the function does not "return a value that is stored as a reference". The function returns a value (a Foo). In your implementation, you are getting this Foo by creating it as a local variable. This is _perfectly_ fine. My answer below does not answer the question in the title, but the question that can be guessed from your code. (Or one of them, at least.)

Comment: @GMan: I think "should this line of code not be a compiler error?" was just bad English for "shouldn't this line of code be a compiler error?"

Comment: Which brings up the question of what compiler kern is using.  It looks to me like it should be a compiler error, and some of the answers specify compilers and their associated compiler errors.

Comment: Sorry for the contradictory text.  I must have made a mistake with the original post.
My question is that the getFoo() returns a temporary value which I keep a reference to that temp copy in the &badfoo.  This to me is a coding error and I am wondering why the compiler would not have caught this error.

My compiler is Visual Studio 2008 ( VC++ )

Comment: Kern, could you please edit the question and the title so that they *both* match what you intended to ask?

Comment: @kern: _All_ functions that return values return "temporary" values. It is up to you to store them somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using VC++ which allows this as an extension.

```
main.cpp:18: warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 
'initializing' : conversion from 'Foo' to 'Foo &'
```

Comment: So based on the comments I've read above I am under the impression that:
a) My example wasn't the best.
b) The compiler should be generating an error for storing a temp value in a reference variable.

Is that the general consensus?  My compiler is VC++ ( MS visual studio 2008 ).

Comment: What you are doing is non-standard. Turn up the warnings level, and the compiler should warn about it. Compilers support things that are not in the standard. VC++ supports binding rvalues to non-const references. GCC supports variable-length arrays etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I could have sworn that I had upped the compiler warnings setting but apparently I had not.
Thanks.  That gives me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

This should be a compile error, although it would not be if it were instead

```
const Foo& badfoo = getFoo();
```

Since there is a special rule that extends the lifetime of temporary values bound to constant references, but only to *constant* references, not any reference.

The code you posted gives me the expected compile error of

> error: invalid initialization of
>   non-const reference of type ‘Foo&’
>   from a temporary of type ‘Foo’

on G++ 4.3.2. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: My compiler is Visual Studio 2008 ( VC++ )

Comment: Then refer to UncleBens' answer; it is legal as an extension provided by VC++, but is illegal in standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

No. `getFoo()` returns a value, this means that a temporary copy of it will be allocated, and the reference will refer to that copy.

Comment: The reference is non-const, a temporary cannot be bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind references to temporaries, and they have the lifetime of the reference itself.

If on the other hand getFoo returned Foo&, you'd have some problems because the lifetime of the object would end when the getFoo function ended.  Since you're not returning a reference to internal data but rather returning a copy of that data, you're fine.

Comment: Binding references to temporaries is only legal for constant references. The compiler should complain about this.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this.  My code example might not have been the best choice.  I'm just trying to understand how I can have a reference to a temporary value object.

Answer (score -1):

The getFoo method could also be like this:

```
 Foo getFoo() 

{
   Foo* myfoo = new Foo();
   myfoo->_x = 10;
   return *myfoo;
}
```

And this is OK... The compiler can't know everything :)

Comment: @GMan - Save the Unicorns:  Leaking memory is legal.  It wouldn't hurt, most of the time, for a compiler to have memory leak warnings, but they certainly aren't required.

Comment: @David: What? Leaking memory is legal, we agree. I'm just pointing out this leaks. Leaks are bad.

Comment: Of course it is not good code (on the contrary - it's pretty bad we agree :)), just wanted to indicate why the compiler can't possibly alert this kind of issue.

Comment: The other problem with this is that it doesn't do anything that the original code didn't, as far as the reference-to-a-temporary issue. You create a `Foo` on the stack, and then return it by value. The return by value simply creates a temporary copy, just like the original code did. The memory used by the heap-allocated `Foo` is leaked, and nothing is gained.